# How many six digits numbers are there such that composed by $2,3,9$ and can be divided by $3$

Tags: combinatorics

> How many six digits numbers are there such that composed by $2,\ 3,\ 9$ and can be divided by $3$ ?
>   **Answer**: $225$.

I know the divisibility rule for $3$ tells: if a number can be divided by $3$ then its digits sum can also be divided by $3$. Can this rule be helpful here?

Comment: Yes it would be helpful.

Comment: @JohnHabert: Could you please explain how?

Comment: It tells you that the only way to use the $2$ is in a group of $3$ or a group of $6$. So no need to try and count things like $223399$ since it can't be divisible by $3$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sum of the digits has to be a multiple of $3$.  Thus there must be either $0$, $3$, or $6$ of the digit 2.

- If there are $0$ 2s, then there are six digits, each of which is a $3$ or a $9$.  So there are $2^6 = 64$ possibilities in this case.
- If there are $3$ 2s, then first you have to choose where to put them, and second you have to choose what the other digits are.  There are $6 \choose 3$ ways to choose slots for the 2s.  Then, there are three digits left, each of which has to be a $3$ or a $9$.  Therefore, there are ${6 \choose 3} 2^3 = 20 \cdot 8 = 160$ possibilities here.
- If there are $6$ 2s, then the number has to be 222222.  There is $1$ possibility.

In total,
$$
64 + 160 + 1 = 225.
$$

Comment: Nice, thanks for the detailed answer!